# wordpress cannot enable comments

Tags: wordpress, comments, blogs

I am trying to add new posts for my site which also should allow posting comments. But when I update, I am getting something like this "Comments are closed".

All the required options have been checked while installing wordpress.

Can anybody let me know as to where I have I done wrong?

Any suggestions are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

In the Settings section of the Dashboard Sidebar, go to Discussion, and make sure the three boxes are ticked under "Default article settings".

This will make all new posts able to accept comments. However, you may have to change that setting manually on each old page or post. Underneath the description box, there should be another box called "Discussion". If this is hidden, you can turn it on at the top under screen options.

Comment: I have done all the said changes but still the same old problem continues. Apart from this, is there any other solution?

Comment: Have you changed the Discussion settings on any individual posts to check that way?